# Oracle: PLSQL query with relaxable where condition - elegant way to realize

Tags: oracle, plsql

Look at the following query. How could I write it in a more readable way?
I'd like to reduce the usage of IF

```
  vSQL := ' SELECT loc.RMV_REMI_VIRTUALE_COD, loc.LOC_DATA_VER_FIN FROM ENI_SAG_TSF_LOCALITA_DEF loc WHERE 1=1 ';
  IF P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD IS NOT NULL THEN
    vSQL := vSQL||' AND LOC.LOC_LOCALITA_COD = '''||P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD||''' ';
  END IF;
  IF P_ISTAT_CITTA IS NOT NULL THEN
    vSQL := vSQL||' AND loc.COMB_ISTAT_COD = '''||P_ISTAT_CITTA||''' ';
  END IF;
  IF P_PLAY_PLAYER_COD IS NOT NULL THEN
    vSQL := vSQL||' AND LOC.PLAY_PLAYER_COD = '''||P_PLAY_PLAYER_COD||''' ';
  END IF;
  IF P_LOC_DATA IS NOT NULL THEN
    vSQL := vSQL||' AND TO_TIMESTAMP ('''||P_LOC_DATA||''' , ''DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF3'') BETWEEN LOC.LOC_DATA_VER_INI AND LOC.LOC_DATA_VER_FIN ';
  END IF;
```

Comment: If you use myBatis, you can implement the query with conditional sql.

Comment: I see whitespaces correctly. How do you see them?

Comment: @gik25, you're asking how to make it more readable; I would double the amount of whitespace...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your answer I found this formulation. What do you think about it?

```
SELECT loc.RMV_REMI_VIRTUALE_COD, loc.LOC_DATA_VER_FIN
  FROM ENI_SAG_TSF_LOCALITA_DEF loc
 WHERE 1 = 1
       AND (LOC.LOC_LOCALITA_COD = :P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD OR :P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD IS NULL)
       AND (loc.COMB_ISTAT_COD = :P_ISTAT_CITTA OR :P_ISTAT_CITTA IS NULL)
       AND (LOC.PLAY_PLAYER_COD = :P_PLAY_PLAYER_COD OR LOC.PLAY_PLAYER_COD IS NULL)
       AND (TO_TIMESTAMP (:P_LOC_DATA, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF3') BETWEEN LOC.LOC_DATA_VER_INI AND LOC.LOC_DATA_VER_FIN OR :P_LOC_DATA IS NULL)
```

Comment: That might be OK for small tables where performance is not an issue. The potential problem is that there is no obvious access path, so it is probably always going to be done as a full table scan. With the dynamic query, the best query is generated according to the criteria entered by the user.

Answer (score 4):

Well I always find code that uses bind variables rather than concatenation of values easier to read (and it is much better practice).  You don't say how the SQL will be run, but assuming a REF CURSOR you could do it like this:

```
vSQL := ' SELECT loc.RMV_REMI_VIRTUALE_COD, loc.LOC_DATA_VER_FIN FROM ENI_SAG_TSF_LOCALITA_DEF loc WHERE 1=1 ';
  IF P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD IS NOT NULL THEN
    vSQL := vSQL||' AND LOC.LOC_LOCALITA_COD = :P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD ';
  ELSE
    vSQL := vSQL||' AND (1=1 OR :P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD IS NULL)';
  END IF;
  IF P_ISTAT_CITTA IS NOT NULL THEN
    vSQL := vSQL||' AND loc.COMB_ISTAT_COD = :P_ISTAT_CITTA ';
  ELSE
    vSQL := vSQL||' AND (1=1 OR :P_ISTAT_CITTA IS NULL)';
  END IF;
  IF P_PLAY_PLAYER_COD IS NOT NULL THEN
    vSQL := vSQL||' AND LOC.PLAY_PLAYER_COD = :P_PLAY_PLAYER_COD ';
  ELSE
    vSQL := vSQL||' AND (1=1 OR :P_PLAY_PLAYER_COD IS NULL)';
  END IF;
  IF P_LOC_DATA IS NOT NULL THEN
    vSQL := vSQL||' AND TO_TIMESTAMP (:P_LOC_DATA, ''DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF3'') BETWEEN LOC.LOC_DATA_VER_INI AND LOC.LOC_DATA_VER_FIN ';
  ELSE
    vSQL := vSQL||' AND (1=1 OR :P_LOC_DATA IS NULL)';
  END IF; 

  OPEN refcur FOR vSQL USING P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD, P_ISTAT_CITTA, P_PLAY_PLAYER_COD, P_LOC_DATA;
```

I added the ELSE clauses because for native dynamic SQL the number of bind variables in the statement has to be fixed.  If using the DBMS_SQL package you don't need to do that.

As for avoiding the IFs, you could do this:

```
vSQL := ' SELECT loc.RMV_REMI_VIRTUALE_COD, loc.LOC_DATA_VER_FIN FROM ENI_SAG_TSF_LOCALITA_DEF loc WHERE 1=1 ';
  || CASE WHEN P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD IS NOT NULL THEN
              ' AND LOC.LOC_LOCALITA_COD = :P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD '
          ELSE
              ' AND (1=1 OR :P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD IS NULL)'
          END
  || CASE WHEN P_ISTAT_CITTA IS NOT NULL THEN
              ' AND loc.COMB_ISTAT_COD = :P_ISTAT_CITTA '
          ELSE
              ' AND (1=1 OR :P_ISTAT_CITTA IS NULL)'
          END
... etc.
```

Obviously you now have CASEs instead, but at least you lose all the `vSQL := vSQL ||` bits.

If you are adding a lot of similar conditions you could wrap the logic in a function like:

```
vSQL := ' SELECT loc.RMV_REMI_VIRTUALE_COD, loc.LOC_DATA_VER_FIN FROM ENI_SAG_TSF_LOCALITA_DEF loc WHERE 1=1 ';
  || and_condition ('LOC.LOC_LOCALITA_COD', 'BV1', P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD)
  || and_condition ('loc.COMB_ISTAT_COD', 'BV2', P_ISTAT_CITTA)
  ... etc.
```

(That doesn't work for the BETWEEN condition of course).

Comment: What do you think about this formulation? (copy on Toad to read)
SELECT loc.RMV_REMI_VIRTUALE_COD, loc.LOC_DATA_VER_FIN
  FROM ENI_SAG_TSF_LOCALITA_DEF loc
 WHERE 1 = 1
       AND (LOC.LOC_LOCALITA_COD = :P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD OR :P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD IS NULL)
       AND (loc.COMB_ISTAT_COD = :P_ISTAT_CITTA OR :P_ISTAT_CITTA IS NULL)
       AND (LOC.PLAY_PLAYER_COD = :P_PLAY_PLAYER_COD OR LOC.PLAY_PLAYER_COD IS NULL)
       AND (TO_TIMESTAMP (:P_LOC_DATA, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF3') BETWEEN LOC.LOC_DATA_VER_INI AND LOC.LOC_DATA_VER_FIN OR :P_LOC_DATA IS NULL)

Answer (score 2):

"More readable" is a little subjective but a couple of options if you don't like the `IF THEN` blocks are:

```
 vSQL := ' SELECT loc.RMV_REMI_VIRTUALE_COD, loc.LOC_DATA_VER_FIN FROM ENI_SAG_TSF_LOCALITA_DEF loc WHERE 1=1 ';

 vSQL := vSQL||
         NVL2(P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD, 
             ' AND LOC.LOC_LOCALITA_COD = '''||P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD||''' ',
              NULL);

 vSQL := vSQL||
         NVL2(P_ISTAT_CITTA,
              ' AND loc.COMB_ISTAT_COD = '''||P_ISTAT_CITTA||''' ',
              NULL);

 vSQL := vSQL||
         NVL2(P_PLAY_PLAYER_COD, 
              ' AND LOC.PLAY_PLAYER_COD = '''||P_PLAY_PLAYER_COD||''' ',
              NULL);

 vSQL := vSQL||
         NVL2(P_LOC_DATA, 
              ' AND TO_TIMESTAMP ('''||P_LOC_DATA||''' , ''DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF3'') BETWEEN LOC.LOC_DATA_VER_INI AND LOC.LOC_DATA_VER_FIN ',
              NULL);
```

or

```
  vSQL := ' SELECT loc.RMV_REMI_VIRTUALE_COD, loc.LOC_DATA_VER_FIN FROM ENI_SAG_TSF_LOCALITA_DEF loc WHERE 1=1 '
        ||NVL2(P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD, 
               ' AND LOC.LOC_LOCALITA_COD = '''||P_LOC_LOCALITA_COD||''' ',
               NULL)
        ||NVL2(P_ISTAT_CITTA,
               ' AND loc.COMB_ISTAT_COD = '''||P_ISTAT_CITTA||''' ',
               NULL)
        ||NVL2(P_PLAY_PLAYER_COD,
               ' AND LOC.PLAY_PLAYER_COD = '''||P_PLAY_PLAYER_COD||''' ',
               NULL)
        ||NVL2(P_LOC_DATA,
               ' AND TO_TIMESTAMP ('''||P_LOC_DATA||''' , ''DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF3'') BETWEEN LOC.LOC_DATA_VER_INI AND LOC.LOC_DATA_VER_FIN ',
               NULL);
```

Hope it helps...